# How to fire filter event on kendo ui grid by Enter keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, kendo-grid

I use Kendo UI v2014.2.716

I have a grid with paging,sorting,filtering by server side, and i enable filter row for my grid.

When i test this filter, i realized that:

- The filters fire when :

  - When input filter lost focus.
  - when user choose item of filter menu.
  - when user click on remove filter button.

And when keypress enter on input filter, this make page postback.

But i  want filter fire when keypress enter on input filter.

So i used template on columns:

```
                { field: "ShortTitle", title: "Title", filterable: { cell: { template: function (input) { input.width("60%"); input.keydown(preventPost); } }} },
```

And write a function to prevent postback:

```
function preventPost(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();             
        }
    }
```

But i don't know how to fire event filter when user press ENTER.

i try to call onblur in preventPost function but it not working.

```
    function preventPost(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.onblur();
        }
    }
```

Please show me the way to do this.Thank so much.

Comment: Does the grid live inside of a form tag?

Answer (score 2):

you can add a function in your column field

```
filterable: {
    cell: {
        operator: "contains",
        template: function (args) {
            args.element.css("width", "90%").addClass("k-textbox").keydown(function (e) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(e.target).trigger("change");
                });
            });
        },
        showOperators: false
    }
}
```

for more information you can refer this link
[https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/filtering/grid-filter-as-you-type](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-filter-as-you-type)